# I have a Problem with a following code PYTHON nameerror: name 'self' is not defined

Tags: python

But this error returns to me.

> NameError: name 'self' is not defined.

```
import pymysql

class DataBase:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = pymysql.connect(
        host='localhost', #ip
        user='root',
        password='',
        db='users-py',
        )

self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

database = DataBase()
```

I want to connect python with a mysql base.

Comment: So, `self` is not defined.

Comment: You can not use `self` outside of the namespace of an instance method. You will have to create an instance of `DataBase` and then access `connection` from there.

Answer (score 0):

The name `self` is not defined because the line below is not indented to be part of the `__init__` method.

```
 self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
```

Solution: indent it.